# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class, runs on local host but does not on AWS tomcat

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat7

This is a simple test application I am using to help get a better understanding of creating dynamic web applications in eclipse. I have read through many of the posts of a similar name, however, none of them helped and I still cannot figure out why it is not working.

The error is:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class LoginCheck

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class LoginCheck
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Root Cause

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: LoginCheck : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class LoginCheck)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3255)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1924)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.94
```

---

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="LoginCheck">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

LoginCheck.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/LoginCheck")

public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoginCheck() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (uname.equals("1") && password.equals("1")) 
        {
            response.sendRedirect("member.jsp");
        }
        else 
        {
            response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
        }

    }

}
```

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: In addition to everything else, writing servlets by hand is like mowing your lawn with scissors. Use a framework like Spring MVC that abstracts all the low-level bits out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported major/minor version errors generally happen due to the difference in your compiler(JDK) and the runtime environment version(JRE). So please make sure you are using the same/compatible versions of JDK+JRE.

Check JDK version in eclipse :

Right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Compiler

Comment: Can you explain how to check jdk version?

Comment: @BrandonT updated the answer to check the JDK version. how are you running your webapp? Using a web container configured in eclipse or deploying to a different container? You need to check what version of JRE is used by your container

Comment: I am running my web app on a tomcat7 server at localhost. While doing this my project works just as intended. However, after exporting the web app as a war file, then taking that file and deploying it to AWS it fails. My project says it is using 1.8 compiler compliance.